# InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, protractor

Following is html snippet element

```html
<a ng-click="nodes.setViewType('tiles',true)">
 <span class="fa fa-check Tick-Inactive" ng-class="nodes.viewType == 'tiles'? 'Tick-Active':'Tick-Inactive'" style=""></span>
                Tile View
</a>
```

Trying to use ng-click or ng-class in locators using java script escape characters. But it showing invalid or illegal selector was specified

```
element(by.xpath("//a[contains(@ng-click,'nodes.setViewType(\'tiles\',true)')]"));

element(by.css("span[ng-class^=nodes.viewType == \'tiles\']"));

element(by.xpath("//a[contains(@ng-click,'nodes.setViewType%28%27tiles%27%2Ctrue%29')]"));
```

Comment: `"//a[contains(@ng-click,\"nodes.setViewType('tiles',true)\")]"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

...implies that the *Locator Strategy* you have constructed was not a valid locator.

To locate the element with text as **Tile View** you can use the following *xpath* :

```
"//a[@ng-click=\"nodes.setViewType('tiles',true)\"]"
```

> **Note** : As the element is an *Angular* element to interact with it you have to induce a waiter for the element to be clickable.