# How to locate the dropdown select element and select an option within a complex website using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, html-select

I have a very complex website which I am trying to test with Selenium. But when I try to get the XPath, I get like this for example.

```
//*[@id="datatable1595356931082"]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/select/option[8]
```

Absolute XPath:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/select/option[8]
```

in Selenium I tried with absolute path like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/")
```

and it tries to error out saying it is unable to find XPath. The datatable seems to create a dynamic number during runtime.
What here I am trying to do is to select a drop down which looks like this

```
<div role="columnheader" class="webix_hcell webix_ss_filter">
<select>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
.
.
.
</select>
</div>
```

I have also tried

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('webix_hcell webix_ss_filter')
```

But that too errors out

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".webix_hcell webix_ss_filter"}
```

For the above one

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/ because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work, because **`*_by_class_name`** is only for single class name:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('webix_hcell webix_ss_filter')
```

Try using **`*_by_css_selector`**:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.webix_hcell.webix_ss_filter select')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to consider as follows:

- From your first attempt the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) appears as a dynamic element due to presence of the *id* attribute value as `datatable1595356931082`, which possibly will change on every access or periodically:

  ```
  //*[@id="datatable1595356931082"]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/select/option[8]
  ```
- In your second attempt you have used an absolute [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath). As the website is dynamic, elements will be repositioned  on every access or periodically:

  ```
  /html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/select/option[8]
  ```
- In your third attempt the *xpath* ends with `/` which isn't desired. Hence you face [InvalidSelectorException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003307/invalidselectorerror-invalid-selector-unable-to-locate-an-element-with-the-xpa/50005362#50005362)
- In your forth attempt you have passed multiple classes through `driver.find_element_by_class_name('webix_hcell webix_ss_filter')` where as `driver.find_element_by_class_name()` accepts only one *classname* as an argument.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted error using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-using-selenium/53536022#53536022)

- Finally, it's a [`<select>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250668/message-element-option-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view-while-trying-to-click/51252175#51252175) node, so you need to use the `Select` class.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to select a drop-down menu value with Selenium using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python/62735660#62735660)

---

### Solution

The relevant text based HTML would have helped us to construct a canonical answer. However as per the HTML provided to click on the option with text as **A** you can use the following either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and `select_by_visible_text()`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='webix_hcell webix_ss_filter' and @role='columnheader']//following::select[1]"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text('A')
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `select_by_value()`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "div.webix_hcell.webix_ss_filter[role='columnheader'] +select"))))
  select.select_by_value('A')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```